# Finding real solutions to $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt[3]{x^2-1}+\sqrt[4]{x^3+15}=x^2+2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I found that $x=1$ is a solution of 
$$\sqrt{x}+\sqrt[3]{x^2-1}+\sqrt[4]{x^3+15}=x^2+2.$$

How would one find other real solutions?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha shows $x=1$ is only the integer solution and the other real root is $x=1.574635\ldots$. Link: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csqrt%7Bx%7D%2B%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7Bx%5E2-1%7D%2B%5Csqrt%5B4%5D%7Bx%5E3%2B15%7D%3Dx%5E2%2B2

Comment: defining $f=\sqrt{x}+(x^2-1)^{1/3}+(x^3+15)^{1/4}-x^2-2$ we get that the equation $f=0$ has exactly two solutions.

Comment: I imagine a polynomial of degree 24 or maybe even 144 would capture those roots.  Newton is still your only hope of finding other roots.

Comment: @Michael: It's actually a degree $48$. Let $x = y^2$, then the $48$-deg can be found by WA as $Factor[Resultant[ (y + z - (y^4 + 2) )^4 - (y^6 + 15), y^4 - 1 - z^3, z]]$. Link is [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor%5BResultant%5B%28y+%2B+z+-+%28y%5E4+%2B+2%29%29%5E4+-+%28y%5E6+%2B+15%29%2C+y%5E4+-+1+-+z%5E3%2C+z%5D%5D) The other root is $y\approx 1.25484$ Since, $x=y^2$, then $x \approx 1.57463$ the same as found by Leibovici.

Answer (score 1):

As Dr. Sonnhard Graubner commented, the problem is to find the second $x$ intercept of function $$f(x)=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt[3]{x^2-1}+\sqrt[4]{x^3+15}-x^2-2$$ Such a monster will not show any analytical solution and only numerical methods (such as [Newton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)) will do the job.

I suppose that, from a plot of the function, you noticed that the root is close to $x_0=1.5$. So, using this value as a starting point and applying Newton method, the iterates would be $$x_1=1.579472329$$ $$x_2=1.574652774$$ $$x_3=1.574635699$$ which is the solution for ten significant figures.

Answer (score 1):

To find a polynomial with that root:
You have $A+B+C=x^2+2$.  Consider $(x^2+2)^2=(A+B+C)^2= x+B^2+C^2+2AB+2AC+2BC$.
Take the first 25 powers of $x^2+2$, from $1=(x^2+2)^0$ to $(x^2+2)^{24}$.  They will all be linear combinations of $A,B,C,B^2,C^2,C^3,AB,AB^2,AC,ABC,AB^2C,...$ with coefficients that are polynomials in $x$. But that is a 24-dimensional space, so there is a linear relation between the 25 formulas.  This linear relation is a polynomial in $x$.